# Will the code after false "if" statements be compiled

Tags: php, performance

if I have code like that

```
if($abc==true) {
   //code code code
} else {
   // other code, other code
}
```

So if `$abc` is `true` will the "other code" be compiled?

So is this irrelevant if there is a lot of "code" performance wise?

Comment: Yes, it will be compiled (actually tokenized and parsed); PHP has no way of knowing what value will be assumed by `$abc`. You can reduce the load somewhat (but only if it is REALLY a lot of code!) by using include() inside the IFs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP is a parsed (and therefore "compiled") at runtime. All of the code is processed, regardless of reachability. For instance:

```
<?php
echo "Hello, World!";
exit;
DERP!!
?>
```

Will fail with a Parse Error rather than printing "Hello, World!", even though the derp can't ever be reached.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will be compiled (actually read, tokenized and parsed); PHP has no way of knowing what value will be assumed by `$abc` at runtime.

You can reduce the load somewhat (but only if it is REALLY a lot of code!) by using include() inside the IFs:

```
 if (condition)
 {
     include('true.php');
 }
 else
 {
     include('false.php');
 }
```

But note that this way you will load *two* files instead of one. Usually, the overhead of the extra file makes the game not worth the effort.

However, if the IF is really a lot lot lot of code, then dividing it in several files might be a good idea maintenance-wise. Refactoring to remove the IF from the program flow would be even better!

Answer (score 1):

Although the entire code is 'parsed' for errors at runtime, the flow of code will only go in one direction at that 'if' point, so there's basically no speed performance issue.

It's really not worth worrying about, especially since flow control statements such as 'if' are probably the most vital elements of programming. You can't get by without them, really.

Answer (score 1):

What performance problems are you concerned about? PHP is an interpreted language which means your files are parsed, tokenized, and executed on every request. The entire file needs to be parsed and tokenized for syntax errors no matter what. What is executed depends on your control flow statements, like the **if** in your example.

If you're concerned about extra parsing, you can refactor your code to include another file based on the result of a control flow statement.

```
$x = 1;
if($x === 1) {
    include_once './myFile.php';
}
else {
    // Something Else.
}
```

Though I can't really think of a huge reason related to performance as to why you would want to do that.